# Preciso criar exceções que façam algo já por padrão e tenham o mesmo comportamento do StandartError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Olá,

Trabalho com Rails e utilizo Sentry para logar os erros de minhas aplicações automaticamente. Quando uma exceção é lançada o erro não é gerado, então tenho que forçar a captura do error através do comando:

```
Raven.captureMessage(e.message, level: 'error')
```

Porém não gostaria de que em quase todo exception ter que repetir essa linha.

Tentei criar uma classe para evitar a repetição, mas acabei não tendo êxito, segue minha tentativa (arquivo criado em lib/raven_error.rb):

```
class RavenError < StandardError
    def initialize exception
        super
        Raven.captureMessage(exception.message, level: 'error')
    end
end
```

Controlador exemplo:

```
    def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    begin
        @user.save
    rescue RavenError => e
        render :new
    end
```

Gostaria que o método captureMessage fosse executado ao instanciar a exceção RavenError, sem ter que ficar requisitando dentro de todo rescue que tenho.

Comment: Pelo jeito o Raven/Sentry não implementa auto captura de exceções. Se ainda puder trocar, recomendo o Bugsnag.

Comment: Ele captura automaticamente, porém dentro de um try catch ele não acha que é um erro, pois a validação é tratada e o sistema não gera log, então nesse tipo de caso precisa-se chamar manualmente.